# Animated anchors do not work in Lynx

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, anchor, screen-readers, lynx

I have several anchors on my one-page-design-site. Those who are animated by JavaScript do not work in screen-reader lynx.
Clicking one of these links always target the first anchor on this page.

As Javascript does not influence (normally) a screen-reader's behavior - what can I do?

@Allan: Thanks for trying to help!
So here is some code: The link to the main navigation, only seen by screen-readers jumps directly to the link with the id "mainnavi":

```
<p class="sreenreader-only">
<a href="#mainnavi">Direct to Main Nav</a>
</p>
<a href="#home" id="mainnavi">Home</a>
```

The link "Home" is animated to scroll down to the section "home", coded like this:

```
<section id="home">...</section>
```

That's all it is.
Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Please provide some code so I can provide better help.

My guess is : Make sure your anchors have unique names

```
<a href="#name1">Menu Item 1</a>
<a href="#name2">Menu Item 2</a>


<a name="name1"></a>

Content 1 .....


<a name="name2"></a>
Content 1 .....
```